# Flashplayer 11.1 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: flash, install-from-source, adobe

I am new to Ubuntu and I've visited pretty much every webpage that exists on the internet about how to install canonical Flashplayers. Ubuntu 12.04 comes with Adobe Flashplayer 11.2 but that is not the most recent version and Adobe no longer supports Ubuntu apparently. I have no idea how to install Flashplayer 11.1 via Terminal. I was able to find a site with canonicals (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/flashplugin-nonfree) but I have no clue where to go from there, though I've tried for approx. 4 hours to figure it out on my own. I am hoping someone could take me step by step through the exact code. For example, "download, then install file" is not specific enough since I am completely new to this. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the latest version of flash installed, you will have to install Chrome at https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/

Flash for Linux will be the latest version in Chrome only at the moment.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-install-google-chrome-in-ubuntu-linux-12-xx-13-xx/ has instructions on how to install Chrome once you download it.

Chrome and Flash will show up in the update manager when a new version come out.  Therefore, once you install Chrome, you can install the latest version of Chrome and Flash easily.

Once you install Chrome, you can remove flash through the Ubuntu Software Manager since Chrome has Flash built-in.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this few steps:

1. Download flash player .tar.gz
2. Extract it and you can see usr and libflashplayer.so
3. Now open terminal and use this command (in folder where you have extracted usr and libflash...) for copy usr folder

> sudo cp -r usr/* /usr
>
> Copy libflashplayer.so to /usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins with this command (in folder where you have extracted usr and libflash...)
>
> For firefox
>
> > sudo cp libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins

For chromium

> sudo cp libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/chromium-browser/plugins

Comment: Marko, Thank you for responding. I have some questions about the details. I tried it and I only got as far as Step 3. What is supposed to go where the * is? I saved the .tar.gz file to my desktop, extracted it on the desktop, then I tried substituting the * for Desktop and it didn't work. Can you be more specific please?

Comment: When you open terminal and use:`cd /home/YOURUSERNAME/Desktop` and  `sudo cp -r usr/*"space"/usr` Then all files under usr folder on desktop copy on they right places.

Answer (score 0):

To update flash player to newer version you can do the following:
In the command line / terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
```

This should add partner repository to apt utility that you can use to download and update packages. Next,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

The first one updates apt-get utility so that it knows that new packages are available, and then upgrade , well, upgrades all the packages, which includes flash player among many other things.

So it the end you should have version 11.2.202.378 , which is latest on Adobe website.

Alternatively you can download Ubuntu Restricted Extras in the software center.

**Alternatives** : Nowadays there are alternatives to Adobe flash player, particularly GNU Shockwave Flash (SWF) and Lightspark. They are a pretty decent idea if you want to make your machine free from proprietary software and dive into open source as much as possible. Also, these projects will definitelly continue to develop now that the need for alternative flashplayer on Linux systems is more than ever high.
You can easily get them through Ubuntu Software Center, just search for gnash and lightspark respectivelly. Using command line , that would be

```
sudo apt-get install gnash
sudo apt-get install lightspark
```

More about them here :http://www.pcworld.com/article/250784/for_flash_on_linux_there_are_open_player_alternatives.html

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/gnash/

Another alternative is pepper flash player which is what google chrome uses. As chromebooks are basicaly google's linux distro, peper flash will definitelly be supported, and it should work for other linux distros ,too. Some people mentioned  installing chrome, but if you might not wanna download chrome, then you can try this:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:skunk/pepper-flash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pepflashplugin-installer

Look at this if you're interested: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-get-chromes-latest-flash-player-to-work-in-firefox-on-linux/
And this: http://www.noobslab.com/2014/01/pepper-flash-alternative-to-adobe-flash.html

At this point I haven't much other ideas, so let me know if this helps, and other folks - please post comments with suggested edits to my answer.